# How can I draw float coordinates in a 500x500 picturebox?

Tags: c#, draw, polygon, picturebox, points

I have this doubt, suddenly something more mathematical, for example I have the following geographical coordinates:

- (4.80549328, -74.14376602)
- (4.80755020, -74.14195687)
- (4.80011076, -74.13276181)
- (4.79816079, -74.13459823)
- (4.80009735, -74.13592503)

They are forming a polygon vertices, we see that they are very small dots together, which place them directly in pixels does not have any effect. How do I scale a 500x500px box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is all under a `Graphics` class, you can simply use the `ScaleTransform` method, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327665%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

To get the scale factor, what you need to do is find the largest x and y coords. Use the largest one and then divide 500 by it, and use that factor both the x and y scaling factor, to maintain the aspect ratio.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Let's say not much, but that's the idea.

Comment: Succeeded out as follows :)!

Make the process for both x and y. For example for X; Rest the highest with the lowest, 500 divided by the result of the subtraction, this gives me the factor now for each x, rest the largest number x we want to locate, this result is multiplied by the factor and thats it. (500/(4.80755020-4.79816079)) = 42601.185804(Factor) Get a Point: (4.80755020-4.80549328) * 42601.185804(Factor) = 87.62718850